# What must I know to use GNU Screen properly?

Tags: gnu-screen

I've just introduced a friend to **GNU Screen** and they're having a hard time getting used to it. That makes me think about the essential things he needs to know about the excellent **Screen** utility, the same things that you'd think worthwhile to teach someone, a beginner, from the ground up. What are some analogies and handy tips for remembering binds, etc.?

It would be awesome.

Comment: There are some good answers to this also in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661/what-is-gnu-screen

Comment: Someone has posted a similar question to this on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/81544/hidden-features-of-screen).

Comment: If someone is just getting started with and having a hard time with Screen, they might want to check out the alternative [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I've been using `Screen` for over 10 years and probably use less than half the features. So it's definitely not necessary to learn all its features right away (and I wouldn't recommend trying). My day-to-day commands are:

```
^A ^W - window list, where am I
^A ^C - create new window
^A space - next window
^A p - previous window
^A ^A - switch to previous screen (toggle)
^A [0-9] - go to window [0-9]
^A esc - copy mode, which I use for scrollback
```

I think that's it. I sometimes use the split screen features, but certainly not daily. The other tip is if screen seems to have locked up because you hit some random key combination by accident, do both `^Q` and `^A ^Q` to try to unlock it.

Comment: ^A k should be added to the list to close a window.

Comment: I don't use ^A k because of the possibility of accidentally killing more than I intend. Instead, I just exit out of the shell in a window using ^D (or `exit`). The screen window automatically closes after exiting the last shell in a window.

Comment: "^A esc - copy mode, which I use for scrollback"  
You are a god amongst men, sir.

Comment: ^A [ does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for ^A ^D trick... I was stuck and couldn't get back to my session.  In case this helps someone I wrote an article a while back which explains the basic of screens like here but has a few more tricks http://www.geekpad.ca/blog/post/managing-multiple-servers-using-screen-terminal-multiplexer

Comment: Thank you so much for ^A^Q!!!

Also, I would add to this list:  ^A d - detaches the screen, leaving it running.  You can then log out of shell and your processes will still run, and then you can come back and reattach the screen with 'screen -r [pid]'.  You can also name your screen when you start it, with 'screen -S screen_name'.  I leave a screen named 'LogFiles' running, tailing multiple log files, so then when I want to see all my logs I just reattach and re-split the screen.

Comment: ^A A to rename the windows, otherwise all screen are named "bash" and you never now which one to select.

Answer (score 39):

I couldn't get used to screen until I found a way to set a 'status bar' at the bottom of the screen that shows what 'tab' or 'virtual screen' you're on and which other ones there are. Here is my setup:

```
[roel@roel ~]$ cat .screenrc
# Here comes the pain...
caption always "%{=b dw}:%{-b dw}:%{=b dk}[ %{-b dw}%{-b dg}$USER%{-b dw}@%{-b dg}%H %{=b dk}] [ %= %?%{-b dg}%-Lw%?%{+b dk}(%{+b dw}%n:%t%{+b dk})%?(%u)%?%{-b dw}%?%{-b dg}%+Lw%? %{=b dk}]%{-b dw}:%{+b dw}:"

backtick 2 5 5 $HOME/scripts/meminfo
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{+b dw}:%{-b dw}:%{+b dk}[%{-b dg} %0C:%s%a %{=b dk}]-[   %{-b dw}Load%{+b dk}:%{-b dg}%l %{+b dk}] [%{-b dg}%2`%{+b dk}] %=[ %{-b dg}%1`%{=b dk} ]%{-b dw}:%{+b dw}:%<"

sorendition "-b dw"
[roel@roel ~]$ cat ~/scripts/meminfo
#!/bin/sh
RAM=`cat /proc/meminfo | grep "MemFree" | awk -F" " '{print $2}'`
SWAP=`cat /proc/meminfo | grep "SwapFree" | awk -F" " '{print $2}'`
echo -n "${RAM}kb/ram ${SWAP}kb/swap"
[roel@roel ~]$
```

Comment: Check out byobu (screen-profiles), too: https://launchpad.net/byobu

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. I was struggling to figure out what was actually happening when I was trying to split my terminal. I didn't realize I needed to run screen first in order to get any of these commands to work, silly, I know.

Answer (score 30):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> ? - show the help screen!

Comment: I completely agree with this. This is much more useful than other answers, since you can deduct the other commands by it, but you cannot do it vice versa. Also it is a lot easier to remember the thing.

Answer (score 26):

If your friend is in the habit of pressing `^A` to get to the beginning of the line in Bash, he/she is in for some surprises, since `^A` is the screen command key binding. Usually I end up with a frozen screen, possibly because of some random key I pressed after `^A` :-)

In those cases I try

`^A s` and `^A q` block/unblock terminal scrolling

to fix that. To go to the beginning of a line inside screen, the key sequence is `^A a`.

Comment: It's easy to change the escape character from ^A to something else.  I've put the details in my answer.

Comment: @agnul +1 for you for **^A a** I'm a user of ^A in a normal bash session and I can't use it inside a screen session. Thanks for the great tip! :)

Comment: Thank you 100 times to you for telling me how to get ctrl A working inside screen. Been looking for this all my life.

Comment: Is the 'A' and 'a' case sensitive here?

Comment: thank you for beginning of line key seq! super helpful.

Answer (score 12):

You can remap the escape key from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to be another key of your choice, so if you do use it for something else, e.g. to go to the beginning of the line in bash, you just need to add a line to your ~/.screenrc file. To make it ^b or ^B, use:

```
escape ^bB
```

From the command line, use names sessions to keep multiple sessions under control. I use one session per task, each with multiple tabs:

```
  screen -ls         # Lists your current screen sessions
  screen -S <name>   # Creates a new screen session called name
  screen -r <name>   # Connects to the named screen sessions
```

When using screen you only need a few commands:

```
  ^A c          Create a new shell
  ^A [0-9]      Switch shell
  ^A k          Kill the current shell
  ^A d          Disconnect from screen
  ^A ?          Show the help
```

An excellent quick reference can be found [here](http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference). It is worth bookmarking.

Comment: I use nested screen sessions. I start the outer one with `screen -e^oo` so I can use Ctrl+O for that and then start the inner ones with `screen -m` so they start new sessions.

Comment: You can change the escape key on the fly. In a running screen session, type `^A :` followed by `\Bb` followed by Enter to set the escape key to ^B. In general, `^A :` lets you evaluate command that your `.screenrc` understands.

Answer (score 9):

Some tips for those sorta familiar with screen, but who tend to not remember things they read in the man page:

- To change the name of a screen window is very easy: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
- Did you miss the last message from screen? <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> will show it again for you.
- If you want to run something (like tailing a file) and have screen tell you when there's a change, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> on the target window. Warning: it will let you know if *anything* changes.
- Want to select window 15 directly? Try these in your `.screenrc` file:

> ```
> bind  ! select 11
> bind  @ select 12
> bind \# select 13
> bind  $ select 14
> bind  % select 15
> bind \^ select 16
> bind  & select 17
> bind  * select 18
> bind  ( select 19
> bind  ) select 10
> ```

That assigns <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>0 through 9</kbd> for windows 10 through 19.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is the base command

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> = go to the ***N***ext screen

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> = go to the ***P***revious screen

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> = ***C***reate new screen

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> = ***D***etach your screen

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is a special key.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> - [d]etach, leave programs (irssi?) in background, go home.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> [c]reate a new window
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>0-9</kbd> switch between windows by number

screen -r - get back to detached session

That covers 90% of use cases. Do not try to show all the functionality at the single time.

Comment: Although, when i first learned about `screen` I was confused about what it _actually_ meant to _detach_ and _re-attach_ a screen. [Quote](http://www.keltia.net/programs/screen/) : "...you can have long-time running tasks in separate consoles (like ssh on a remmote machine, IRC sessions, …) on a given machine, detach from the session, move from one physical location to another, connect to the machine through ssh and re-attach to the screen session to keep on working."

Answer (score 6):

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/34

I wrote that a couple of years ago, but it is still a good introduction that gets a lot of positive feedback.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: `$VAR1 = \'Can\'t connect to local MySQL server through socket \'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\' (111 "Connection refused") at ../lib/Singleton/DBI.pm line 95. '; `

Answer (score 6):

I "must" add this: add

```
bind s
```

to your `.screenrc`, if You - like me - used to use split windows, as `C-a S` splits the actual window, but `C-a s` freezes it. So I just disabled the freeze shortcut.

Comment: `^-Q` unfreezes if you hit `^-S`

Comment: You are right @Plato. Still I'm working in environment with users, who won't memorize almost any of the shortcuts... I needed to disable it.

Comment: NP i just found this thread first and searched 'freeze' and didn't find what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Not really essential not solely related to screen, but [enabling 256 colors in my terminal, GNU Screen and Vim](https://web.archive.org/web/20130313011037/http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/) improved my screen experience big time (especially since I code in Vim about 8h a day - there are some great eye-friendly colorschemes).

Answer (score 3):

There is some [interesting work](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2008/12/ubuntu-server-includes-window-manager.html) being done on getting a good GNU screen setup happening by default in the next version of Ubuntu Server, which includes using the bottom of the screen to show all the windows as well as other useful machine details (like number of updates available and whether the machine needs a reboot). You can probably grab their `.screenrc` and customise it to your needs.

The most useful commands I have in my `.screenrc` are the following:

```
shelltitle "$ |bash" # Make screen assign window titles automatically
hardstatus alwayslastline "%w" # Show all window titles at bottom line of term
```

This way I always know what windows are open, and what is running in them at the moment, too.

Answer (score 3):

The first modification I make to .screenrc is to change the escape command.  Not unlike many of you, I do not like the default Ctrl-A sequence because of its interference with that fundamental functionality in almost every other context.  In my .screenrc file, I add:

escape `e

That's backtick-e.

This enables me to use the backtick as the escape key (e.g. to create a new screen, I press backtick-c, detach is backtick-d, backtick-? is help, backtick-backtick is previous screen, etc.).  The only way it interferes (and I had to break myself of the habit) is using backtick on the command line to capture execution output, or pasting anything that contains a backtick.  For the former, I've modified my habit by using the BASH $(command) convention.  For the latter, I usually just pop open another xterm or detach from screen then paste the content containing the backtick.  Finally, if I wish to insert a literal backtick, I simply press backtick-e.

Comment: brilliant.  I use backticks all the time, even though I know I ought to use $(...), so now I guess I might have to change my ways.   
  The backtick is a little out of the way, but it's nice to have a single key without modifiers needed.  But why "e", and how do you remember that?

Comment: I just tested 'escape ``' and it works nicely and seems easier to remember.  If you hit backtick and don't get what you are expecting, just hit it again.

Comment: I have done this, but is there a way to actually type a backtick while in screen? Sometimes, it's necessary to do this, and I hate having to detach to do it...

Comment: @Guillouchon: the previous comment explains exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following for `ssh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# scr - Runs a command in a fresh screen
#
# Get the current directory and the name of command

wd=`pwd`
cmd=$1
shift

# We can tell if we are running inside screen by looking
# for the STY environment variable.  If it is not set we
# only need to run the command, but if it is set then
# we need to use screen.

if [ -z "$STY" ]; then
        $cmd $*
else
        # Screen needs to change directory so that
        # relative file names are resolved correctly.
        screen -X chdir $wd

        # Ask screen to run the command
        if [ $cmd == "ssh" ]; then
                screen -X screen -t ""${1##*@}"" $cmd $*
        else
                screen -X screen -t "$cmd $*" $cmd $*
        fi
fi
```

Then I set the following bash aliases:

```
vim() {
        scr vim $*
}

man() {
        scr man $*
}

info() {
        scr info $*
}

watch() {
        scr watch $*
}

ssh() {
        scr ssh $*
}
```

It opens a new screen for the above aliases and iff using ssh, it renames the screen title with the ssh hostname.

Comment: You want `"$@"`instead of `$*` throughout.

Answer (score 2):

I like to set up a screen session with descriptive names for the windows. ^a A will let you give a name to the current window and ^a " will give you a list of your windows.
When done, detach the screen with ^a d and re-attach with screen -R

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `screen -d -RR` to automatically create/attach to a given screen. I created bash functions to make it easier...

```
function mkscreen
{
    local add=n

    if [ "$1" == '-a' ]; then
        add=y
        shift;
    fi

    local name=$1;
    shift;
    local command="$*";

    if [ -z "$name" -o -z "$command" ]; then
        echo 'Usage: mkscreen [ -a ] name command

    -a          Add to .bashrc.' 1>&2;
        return 1;
    fi

    if [ $add == y ]; then
        echo "mkscreen $name $command" >> $HOME/.bashrc;
    fi

    alias $name="/usr/bin/screen -d -RR -S $name $command";

    return 0;
}

function rmscreen
{
    local delete=n

    if [ "$1" == '-d' ]; then
        delete=y
        shift;
    fi

    local name=$1;

    if [ -z "$name" ]; then
        echo 'Usage: rmscreen [ -d ] name

    -d          Delete from .bashrc.' 1>&2;
        return 1;
    fi

    if [ $delete == y ]; then
        sed -i -r "/^mkscreen $name .*/d" $HOME/.bashrc;
    fi

    unalias $name;

    return 0;
}
```

They create an alias to `/usr/bin/screen -d -RR -S $name $command`. For example, I like to use irssi in a screen session, so in my .bashrc (beneath those functions), I have:

```
mkscreen irc /usr/bin/irssi
```

Then I can just type `irc` in a terminal to get into irssi. If the screen 'irc' doesn't exist yet then it is created and /usr/bin/irssi is run from it (which connects automatically, of course). If it's already running then I just reattach to it, forcibly detaching any other instance that is already attached to it. It's quite nice.

Another example is creating temporary screen aliases for perldocs as I come across them:

```
mkscreen perlipc perldoc perlipc
perlipc # Start reading the perldoc, ^A d to detach.
...
# Later, when I'm done reading it, or at least finished
# with the alias, I remove it.
rmscreen perlipc
```

The -a option (must be first argument) appends the screen alias to .bashrc (so it's persistent) and -d removes it (these can potentially be destructive, so use at own risk). xD

Append:

Another bash-ism that I find convenient when working a lot with screen:

```
alias sls='/usr/bin/screen -ls'
```

That way you can list your screens with a lot fewer keystrokes. I don't know if `sls` collides with any existing utilities, but it didn't at the time on my system so I went for it.

Answer (score 0):

^A A switches back to the screen you just came from.

Comment: ^A ^A switches back, ^A A allows rename window's title.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is a great special character for Unix people, but if you're using screen to talk to [OpenVMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS), then not being able to ^A is going to make you bald prematurely.

In [VMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS#Origin_and_name_changes), if you're editing a [DCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIGITAL_Command_Language) command prior to execution from the history buffer, Insert mode is off (it has to be for a few reasons I won't get into here) ... to turn it on so you don't over-type your command rather than space things out, you have to hit `^A.

Comment: I use `screen -e ^Ll` for similar reasons; I simply cannot unlearn to type ctrl-A to go to beginning of line in Emacs.  Fortunately, ctrl-L is a keystroke I rarely need, and also it IMHO connects nicely with its general meaning (redraw/clear screen).

Comment: @tripleee: My `.screenrc` has `escape ^@^@`, which uses the null character rather than control-A. On most systems, you can enter the null character as control-space, which is very easy to type. (I have a nested screen session running inside a window in my main session; for that one I have `escape ^]^]`.)