# What is GNU Screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

What is GNU Screen?

Comment: I prefer just to open up a few tabs instead of conflating the same terminal

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What is [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)? Great!

Erm, a slightly more useful answer: it allows you to run multiple console applications, or commands, in one terminal. Kind of like a tabbed terminal emulator. In fact, that's exactly what it is (just not done with the regular GUI toolkits)

Why is it so great? Simple, you can run a program in a screen session (Run `screen` and it runs your default shell, run `screen myapp` and it runs myapp in the session), hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (the screen control sequence) and then press <kbd>d</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd>) to detach.

The program keeps running in the background, *but*, unlike doing `mycmd &`, you can run `screen -r` to reattach the session, and everything is as you left it. You can send input to the command, if it's a curses UI, everything still works just like if it were a "real" terminal.

It's very popular with console IRC clients - you can run (say) `screen irssi` and reattach the session from anywhere you can SSH from.

A few useful commands:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> to make a new virtual terminal (or "window") in the session
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd> to cycle through multiple windows
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> to select window 1, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd> to select window 4 and so on
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to flick between the last two active windows
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (upper-case a) allows you to rename the current window
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd> (for me, that's <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> - the quote mark) lists windows, you can use the arrows and select one. Also useful with the "tab bar" setting I'll list in a second

A few other useful things I've stumbled across:

- Use the `-U` flag when you launch screen so it supports Unicode (for example, `screen -xU`)
- The `-x` flag allows you to reattach the same session multiple times. (`-r` disconnects existing connections)
- You can do interesting stuff with the status bar. I have my setup to display `[ hostname ][ 0-$ bash  (1*$ irssi) ][16/09  9:32]` (Running on hostname, it has two windows. This is set by the hardstatus lines in my .screenrc (at the end of the answer)

```
startup_message off
vbell off
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{gk}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{wk}%?%-Lw%?%{=b kR}(%{W}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{=b kR})%{= kw}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}]%{=y C}[%d/%m %c]%{W}'
```

Comment: *"unlike doing `mycmd &`"* - actually, you can use `fg` to get a process back from the background (where it is sent with `&`), and `ctrl+z` to put it back there.

Comment: @naught101: Sure, that puts it in the background, *but it is still attached to the terminal*. Close the terminal window, or break the connection to the server, and the process also gets closed. `screen` avoids this, by separating the part where the process runs from the part where user interaction happens.