# Debian: SSHing and running a process that won't die if SSH connection is closed

Tags: linux, ssh, compilation, debian

Running a Debian server and would like to install Ruby but it's taking almost an hour on "compiling", and I can never keep my SSH connection up for so long.

I was hoping to SSH into the server, running the installation command and leave it running on the server once I close my SSH connection, and be able to check back on it later.

Is there a way to do that?

Please and thank you in advance!

Comment: See this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it). It suggests using [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Comment: Learn about screen and/or tmux! You won't regret it. tmux is newer and better.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661/what-is-gnu-screen

Comment: @bryn This pretty much answers my question! Thank you! Can you please write it in as an answer so I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating myself, but I am writing an answer so it can be marked as accepted/solved :)

Learn about screen and/or tmux! You won't regret it. tmux is newer and better. stackoverflow.com/questions/70661/what-is-gnu-screen

screen/tmux let's you keep a remote terminal session running that you can connect/reconnect to - I *always* start long running tasks in a screen in case my connection drops (or in case I wanna leave the office and go home ;) ).

Comment: Used Screen, awesome :D Thank you!