# Starting/stopping a background Python process wtihout nohup + ps aux grep + kill

Tags: python, linux, bash, nohup

I usually use:

```
nohup python -u myscript.py &> ./mylog.log &       # or should I use nohup 2>&1 ? I never remember
```

to start a background Python process that I'd like to continue running even if I log out, and:

```
ps aux |grep python
# check for the relevant PID
kill <relevantPID>
```

It works but it's a annoying to do all these steps.

I've read some methods in which you need to save the PID in some file, but that's even more hassle.

---

**Is there a clean method to easily start / stop a Python script?** like:

```
startpy myscript.py             # will automatically continue running in
                                # background even if I log out

# two days later, even if I logged out / logged in again the meantime
stoppy myscript.py
```

Or could this long part `nohup python -u myscript.py &> ./mylog.log &` be written in the shebang of the script, such that I could start the script easily with `./myscript.py` instead of writing the long nohup line?

---

*Note : I'm looking for a one or two line solution, I don't want to have to write a dedicated systemd service for this operation*.

Comment: Well, you can use [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) or [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess) to run a program in the backgound. You can also use [`os.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) instead of GNU `kill`.  [And here's some ways to get a list of running processes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python) But something I don't understand: What do you mean about *two days later, even after some reboot* ?

Comment: @KevinGuan : Sorry, I edited my question (I meant: *two days later even after some log out / log in*). About the first part of your comment: no, I don't want to start or kill a process *from* Python (with `os` module). I want to start / stop a background-running-Python process easily, in one or two lines, from bash.

Comment: Ah, that's fine. I have removed Python tag and added Bash tag since actually you're not *programming in Python*.

Comment: By the way, are you looking for `pkill` or `killall` command? Which kills a process by it's name.

Comment: @KevinGuan Ok for adding bash tag, but I have set python tag again, because sometimes there are specific behaviour when using Python (for example `nohup python myscript...` works bad whereas `nohup python -u myscript...` ensures everyting is written, unbuffered etc.)

Comment: Well, fair enough. Python special question ;)

Comment: `pkill` or `killall` seem to be what you are looking for. Another very hacky, but simple method, is to check in the main loop of your Python for the existence of a file called `/STOP` and delete it and exit if it exists, then you can stop the script with `touch /STOP`. Likewise, you can do `touch /PAUSE` and the script can stop processing and sleep in a loop checking each time it wakes if `/PAUSE` exists. Crude but easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there are just two (or maybe three or maybe four?) solutions to the problem of running background scripts on remote systems.

**1) nohup**

```
nohup python -u myscript.py > ./mylog.log  2>&1 &
```

**1 bis) disown**

Same as above, slightly different because it actually remove the program to the shell job lists, preventing the SIGHUP to be sent.

**2) screen (or tmux as suggested by neared)**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661/what-is-gnu-screen) you will find a starting point for screen.

See this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and) for a great explanation of how background processes works. Another related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797050/how-to-run-process-as-background-and-never-die).

**3) Bash**

Another solution is to write two bash functions that do the job:

```
mynohup () {
    [[ "$1" = "" ]] && echo "usage: mynohup python_script" && return 0
    nohup python -u "$1" > "${1%.*}.log" 2>&1 < /dev/null &
}

mykill() {
    ps -ef | grep "$1" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
    echo "process "$1" killed"
}
```

Just put the above functions in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` and use them as normal bash commands.

Now you can do exactly what you told:

```
mynohup myscript.py             # will automatically continue running in
                                # background even if I log out

# two days later, even if I logged out / logged in again the meantime
mykill myscript.py
```

**4) Daemon**

This [daemon module](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/77fdb0012b72ebdf4c9d19d6256a1119) is very useful:

```
python myscript.py start

python myscript.py stop
```

Comment: Is it possible to make such a bash function `myrun` that will be used with `myrun script.py` that 1) reads the first line of `script.py`, remove the leading `#MYRUN:` 2) execute the command written in this first line. Example: doing `myrun script.py` with [this file](http://pastebin.com/u7KVhMLx) will execute `nohup python -u script.py &`.

Comment: I started a question about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829145/a-bash-function-that-runs-script

Comment: I now use `screen` and that's awesome and simple. `screen -s myscript`, then run the script `python myscript.py` then detach with CTRL+A, D, then I can log out etc. To reattach `screen -r myscript`, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean log in and out remotely (e.g. via SSH)? If so, a simple solution is to install tmux (terminal multiplexer). It creates a server for terminals that run underneath it as clients. You open up tmux with `tmux`, type in your command, type in `CONTROL+B+D` to 'detach' from tmux, and then type exit at the main terminal to log out. When you log back in, tmux and the processes running in it will still be running.

Comment: Yes I mean log in and out remotely from SSH (the place where the script is run is a distant server). What happens to tmux when I log out from SSH? Will the Python script continue? Something else: how to avoid to write `nohup python -u myscript.py &> ./mylog.log &` every time? Can I put this thing in shebang?

Comment: When you logout with `logout` or with `exit`, the script will continue to run either way. The only things you will need to type are `tmux`, `command to run`, `CTRL + B + D` (to detach from tmux), and `logout`. When you log back in and want to stop the script, tmux will still be running. You can connect to it with `tmux attach`. As another plus, you can run as many terminal clients in one window as you want. See here for its many configuration options: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html