# why nohup does not launch my script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is my **script.sh**

```
for ((i=1; i<=400000; i++))
do
   echo "loop $i"
   echo 
   numberps=`ps -ef | grep php | wc -l`;
   echo $numberps
   if [ $numberps -lt 110 ]
   then
   php5 script.php &
   sleep 0.25
   else
     echo too much process
    sleep 0.5
fi
done
```

When I launch it with:

```
./script.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

that works except **when I logout from SSH and login again**, I cannot stop the script with `kill%1` and `jobs -l` is empty

When I try to launch it with

```
nohup ./script.sh &
```

It just ouputs

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

**but no php5 are running: nohup has no effect at all**

I have 2 aleternatives to solve my problem:

1)  `./script.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` 
If I logout from SSH and login again, How can I delete this job ?

or 
2) How to make nohup run correctly ?

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you mean `launch` or is there an actual term for `lunch` here that I am unaware of? Serious question.

Comment: sorry.. It was launch of course :D

Comment: All kinds of custom solutions come to mind, but have you tried readily available solutions for this kind of thing like `supervisord`?

Comment: sorry, I am not a linux expert.

Comment: Capture and examine the output of the script to help figure out what is going wrong. Run `bash -x ./script.sh >logfile 2>&1 &` to create a detailed log of what it is doing.  In the 'nohup' case, run `nohup bash -x ./script.sh &`, and examine the 'nohup.out' file after the problem has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

`nohup` is not supposed to allow you to use `jobs -l` or `kill %1` to kill jobs after logging out and in again.

Instead, you can

- Run the script in the foreground in a [GNU Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614/gnu-screen-survival-guide) or tmux session, which lets you log out, log in, reattach and continue the same session.
- `killall script.sh` to kill all running instances of `script.sh` running on the server.

Comment: killall script.sh : process not found after I logout and login again !

Comment: @user300675 If you're getting an error message, please copy-paste the command and entire message rather than typing it from memory. Exact whitespace is important because it points to quoting bugs, exact wording is important because it identifies versions of tools, and entire, unabbreviated command and output can give major clues to issues that just the english message text does not.

Comment: root@email1:/var/www# killall script.sh
script.sh: no process found

Comment: @user300675 Add the missing `#!/bin/bash` shebang to your script and try again.